# Trocar Tag por outra Tag SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte email: `joao@meusite.com.br`, eu preciso trocar tudo que tiver `meusite.com.br` para `seusite.com.br`.

Como eu posso fazer?

A minha ideia era: `UPDATE tabela SET email = email "seusite.com.br"`.. Mas ai não daria certo, iria apenas adicionar.

Comment: depende do SGBD (que vc não mencionou). No MS Sql Server or exemplo tem o comando REPLACE

Comment: Acredito que seria o replace... talvez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve ser feito o seguinte:

```
UPDATE TABELA SET EMAIL = REPLACE(EMAIL,'meusite.com.br','seusite.com.br')
WHERE EMAIL like '%meusite.com.br'
```

Answer (score 3):

Se for SQL Server:

```
Update tabela
    set email = REPLACE(email, "meusite.com.br", "seusite.com.br")
Where email like '%meusite.com.br'
```